# SQL Database with undefined columns

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I'm working on a project where I'm dumping data into a mysql database about different people, however, each person can have many entries so I'm not sure how to have a lot of columns.

e.g

```
Name  id  
jack  234  01241990 13241990 03451993 10945
james 222  01131998 14242001 03414235 10945435 3456363 3465758
jill 1234  01131998 14242001 03414235 10945435 3456363 3465758 4253156316 6427247 583583
```

As you can see there can be many entries for each person, not in 100's, but I think the max can be around 20-30ish? So how do I build a database that I can insert values into without knowing how many entries will be per person, beforehand.

I am using perl script to insert values. Any ideas will be helpful

EDIT: People are suggesting to create two tables, however, when I joint he tables, I want one row for each person.

e.g After joining my view should look like

```
james 222  01131998 14242001 03414235 10945435 3456363 3465758
```

Comment: You need [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Create 2 tables one for `Name, id` other for `id/Name, value`.

Comment: Create a new table for the data and link it back to the person with some fort of unique ID. Each item of data is a separate row in the new table. You can have as many, or as few, as you need.

Comment: when I joint the tables, I want one row for each person and not several. I tried creating a dummy tables, however whenever I join them I get one different rows for different values even it's for the same person.

Comment: The way to do this using a relational database is, as you have been told, to use two tables. The database is a way of *storing* the data: you can display it however you want, although your second table will also need a sequence number if you want to retain the order of the values.

Comment: Will the sequence number be different for each person? or a standard sequence. e.g 1 james 2312, 2 jack 141423, 3 james 241424 OR 1 james 2312, 1 jack 141423, 2 james 241424?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to split the data into two tables (People and Data):

```
People:
NAME  ID
Jack  234
James 222
Jill  1234

Data:
ID  PeopleID Data
1   234      01241990
2   234      13241990
.
.
99  1234     6427247 
100 1234     583583
```

You can then use joins to get the data for each person

```
SELECT p.Name,
       p.ID,
       d.Data
FROM People p
JOIN Data d
    ON d.PeopleID = p.ID
ORDER BY p.Name --(assuming you want names in alphabetical order)
```

You should get something like the following

```
Name ID  Data
Jack 234 01241990
Jack 234 13241990
.
.
Jill 1234 6427247 
Jill 1234 583583
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, so when I join, will the data show just like it was before, different number of fields for different people, and in the same order? Also, instead of using ID's, can I use people's ID that already exists in the data?

Comment: You will get a different row for each Data field:  Jack, 01241990; Jack, 13241990; etc...

Comment: When I join, is there no way to have a single row for each person? So when I join, every entry for Jack gets displayed in one row?